# Mapping EntityFramework One to One without Helper Property

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

### Context:

I have two classes who have two corresponding tables in SQL.

- System info

  EF version: <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />

  SQL version: 2012
- The classes

  ```
  public class Employee
  {
          public Employee(string name,Department department )
          {
              Name = name;
              Department = department;
          }
          public int Id {get;set;}
          public string Name {get;set;}
          public Department Department {get;set;}
  }




  public class Department
  {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
  }
  ```
- The tables
  The columns match the properties with the exception that Employee table has a foreign key column DepartmentId.
- The mapping

  ```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                  .HasKey(e => e.Id)
                  .HasRequired(s => s.Department);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                  .HasKey(e => e.Id);
  }
  ```

### The Problem

When the following commands are issued:

```
dc.Empoyees.Add(new Employee("some employee",department));
dc.SaveChanges();
```

The generated insert SQL statement does not contain the foreign key unless I declare a property of DepartmentId under Employee along with the Department property.

### The Questions

How can the mapping be changed so that EF would generate and insert the correct foreign key 'DepartmentId' into the Employee table?

Or are there other ways?

I do not want to maintain a DepartmentId property when I have Deparment as property already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF will create the FK column for you under the covers if you don't include it in your object, but it will be called **Department_Id** rather than **DepartmentId**. You can override this name as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasKey(e => e.Id)
    .HasRequired(s => s.Department)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("DepartmentId"));
```

Granted, the API is definitely not obvious. Here is a doc with examples for configuring relationships - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to maintain that property but you will need it. That is what the entity framework retrieves and then uses to get the departments then or later.

But if you set the department object that ID should be set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'm looking at EF as an NHibernate alternative.  And in NHibernate, I don't have to have this extra property.  So if I were to migrate from NH to EF, I have to add this property to every domain model (entity)?

Comment: Yeah, [here](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/12/15/entity-framework-4-tips-for-nhibernate-users/) is a good walk through on how they work. It may add an extra block of code to your entity, but the two are automatically synced. I have found it can be useful in a cached system, where if you need to run on update but didn't need to load all of the children entities first. The cached entity will *have* all of the keys you need.

Comment: that doc was for EF 4, I'm using EF 6.  is this still the case?

Comment: Unless something has significantly changed, yes. I believe that is part of the philosophy. [Here is a current document](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which references this need.

Comment: Also @CullenTsering it would be interesting to disassemble the NHibernate objects and see if it is injecting those at compile time or something like that.